# sendRequest removes passing function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome removes the function that I'm trying to pass through sendRequest.

```
function sendQuery() {
  var currentQuery = document.getElementById("queries").value;

  var request = {
    option: "random value",
    command: function() {
      alert("fire!");
    }
  };       

  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, request)
  });
}
```

As you can see, `request` contains function `command`, but when I 'dump' the request that was received by contentscript, everything I get is this:

```
request
  Object
    option: "random value"
    __proto__: Object
```

I need to pass the `command` as well, not just the `option`. Thanks in advance for helping me to do so.

Edit: Edited according to Pointy's suggestion, but the problem remains.

Comment: You should be declaring "request" and "currentQuery" with `var`, almost certainly.

Comment: Fixed, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of [`chrome.tabs.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendRequest) is JSON serialized for transportation.

The one and only way to pass a function is via the third parameter. This function is received as a third parameter at the [`chrome.extension.onRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest) event listener:

```
function sendQuery() {
    var currentQuery = document.getElementById("queries").value;

    var request = { option: "random value" };
    var command = function() {  alert("fire!");  };       

    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
       chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, request, commans);
    });
}
```

Comment: That would explain why is it removed, but how do I collect the third parameter inside contentscript?

Comment: @Grant I have mentioned that in my answer: It is passed as a third argument to the [event listener](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest):  `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, COMMAND_RECEIVED_HERE){ /* ... */ })`.

Comment: I've reduced the whole extension to only 15 lines of code and this is what I get: After execution of `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, COMMAND_RECEIVED_HERE){ 
    alert(COMMAND_RECEIVED_HERE);
  });`
It alerts this: `function (response) {
            if (port) {
              port.postMessage(response);
              port = null;
            } else {
              // We nulled out port when sending the response, and now the page` etc.

But I'm using purely the code you provided me with (thanks for the code, it looks clear)

Comment: @Grant That is correct. The function itself is not passed. It only provides an easy method to call functions (see also: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html#connect).

Comment: Oh, but it is called inside the popup of my extension. What I need to do is to send a function from the popup window to the webpage and execute it there.

Comment: @Grant If the function does not utilise the `chrome.*` API, you can execute code in the context of the webpage using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8996/discussion-between-grant-and-rob-w)